# .htaccess-File to Control the Routing of a certain php file

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have a few php files in my server root directory `https://example.com`.

My current `.htaccess`-file does:

- rewriting (removing the `php` file ending)
- redirect from `/index` to `/`

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /(.+)\.php
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [L,R=301]

Redirect 301 /index /
```

**Let us now consider the following two:**

```
/cart.php
/checkout.php
```

The goal is:

- only response `https://example.com`**`/checkout`** if the referrer is `https://example.com`**`/cart`**, else redirect to `https://example.com`**`/cart`**
- redirect/rewrite from `https://example.com`**`/checkout`** to `https://example.com`**`/cart/checkout`**

Comment: Could you please do mention in form of urls from which url to which url you want to rewrite/redirect? It will make question much clearer, thank you.

Comment: Is the question this way clear?

Comment: Could you please do let me know if this has helped you?

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples of urls and for your requested only this htaccess rules are, could you please try following.

```
RewriteEngine ON
##First rule of getting response of checkout when cart is requested.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/cart/?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ /checkout [NC,L]

##Rewriting to /cart/checkout when checkout is requested.
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/checkout/?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /cart/checkout/? [R=301,NC,L]
```